# Get most common match for each unique item in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data that is similar to these two arrays:

```
predicted_class = ['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A']
true_class_____ = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']
```

I would like to find the number of classes that are correctly predicted once the majority consensus is taken - e.g my data shows predictions for 'A' = 66% correct, 'B' = 66% correct, 'C' = 33% correct, so overall accuracy would be 66% given the most common prediction for class 'A' and 'B' are correct, but 'C' isn't.

Comment: `given the most common prediction for class 'A' and 'B' are correct, but 'C' isn't` what's the criterion here? accuracy being > 50%? or something different?

Comment: To clairfy this, if there were more data and say Class A was classified as A 40% of the time, and as B and C 30% of the time each, then this would count as correct as the most common prediction is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you write in the example and comments, it looks like you are looking for the maximum of the correct-to-all prediction ratio for each class.

Here is one way of doing so using `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections


def max_model_match(true, predicted):
    # count all occurrences of the classes
    counter_all = collections.Counter(true)
    # initialize the "correct" or "good" counter
    counter_good = counter_all.copy()
    counter_good.clear()
    # loop through all outcomes
    for (x, y) in zip(true, predicted):
        # if the prediction is correct increment the counter
        if x == y:
            counter_good[x] += 1
    # find the maximum correct-to-all ratio
    max_good_ratio = 0.0
    for key in counter_all.keys():
        good_ratio = counter_good[key] / counter_all[key]
        if good_ratio > max_good_ratio:
             max_good_ratio = good_ratio
    return max_good_ratio


predicted_class = ['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A']
true_class      = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']
max_model_match(true_class, predicted_class)
# 0.6666666666666666
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using a `defaultdict` and `max`:

```
predicted_class = ['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A']
true_class      = ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : [0, 0]) # [total, correct]
for p,t in zip(predicted_class, true_class):
    d[t][0] += 1
    if p == t:
        d[t][1] += 1

# max value
max(n/t for t,n in d.values())
```

output: `0.666666666`